# Universally quantified (or polymorphic) type class instances

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to define a generic type class instance parameterized by a type `a` in Haskell?
For example:

```
data Box a = Box a deriving Show

class Boxable a where
  create :: a -> Box a

-- pseudo syntax here
instance forall a . Boxable a where
  create = Box
```

If no, why not?

I am aware of the fact that this example is rather simple and "useless". I just want to know whether this is theoretically possible, not whether its practically relevant.

Comment: This would just duplicate regular parametric polymorphism; the point of a type class is to support *non*-parametric polymorphism.

Comment: Feel free to add this as answer @chepner! Also, if you like, elaborate on your comment. :)

Comment: If you remove `forall a .` from your code and enable a couple of extensions it should compile. (It does not look very useful, though.)

Comment: @NiklasVest Since it doesn't actually constrain the type, the method `create` is equivalent to a regular polymorphic function `create :: a -> Box a`. However, I wouldn't discount the possibility that it could serve some purpose in type-level (or even kind-level) programming, a sort of multiplicative identity for an operator that combines `Constraint` values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is literally legal Haskell, nothing “pseudo syntax” about it. It's not quite Haskell98, but with two very harmless syntactic extensions it does compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForall, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Box a = Box a deriving Show

class Boxable a where
  create :: a -> Box a

instance forall a . Boxable a where
  create = Box
```

The `-XExplicitForall`<sup>†</sup> is required for the explicit `forall` (duh), but actually you don't even need this because Haskell type variables are by default universally quantified:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Boxable a where
  create = Box
```

Except, like chepner already commented this doesn't really make sense, because now `create` behaves just like a regular parametric function without any typeclass needed:

```
create' :: a -> Box a
create' = Box
```

That said, such once-and-for-all instances *can* actually be useful, if you constrain them with some superclass:

```
class Foo a
class Bar a

class (Foo a, Bar a) => FooBar a

instance (Foo a, Bar a) => FooBar a
```

Now if you mention `FooBar (someComplicatedType)` in a function's constraints, it has the same effect as writing out `(Foo (someComplicatedType), Bar (someComplicatedType)`, which can significantly de-clunk your code and error messages and also make your projects more future-safe, because you can add or remove superclasses to `FooBar` without changing the signatures of all the functions that have this constraint.

(A very similar thing can be achieved with `-XConstraintKinds` as the arguably more straightforward *constraint synonym* `type FooBar a = (Foo a, Bar a)`, but this brings in the well-known problem that `type` isn't really an encapsulation at all but can be unravelled by the compiler at any time, which isn't normally much of a problem except it leads to much more confusing type error messages.)

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>You won't find `-XExplicitForall` itself very often in Haskell files, because it's only really needed as part of either `-XScopedTypeVariables` or `-XRankNTypes`, both of which are common and enable the `forall` keyword, or `∀` as I prefer to write it (which additionally requires `-XUnicodeSyntax`).</sub>

Comment: Full `ScopedTypeVariables` is not needed. Just `ExplicitForAll` does it.

Comment: Really great answer. The fact that the syntax actually works got me good! Also, thank you for the further elaboration on that use case of constraints!

Comment: Constraint synonyms aren't first-class, so I prefer to offer classes when possible. I'll sometimes use the pattern `type FooF a b c = some big constraint; class FooF a b c => Foo a b c; instance FooF a b c => Foo a b c`. I also often do this for a type family `FooF`.